# How to collect osm-meta-util from one region?

Tags: metadata, openstreetmap

i am following OSM-Meta-util and collecting metadata for my Project.
i can see all changes that being maid in json file. for example:

```
{"id":"19739143","created_at":"2013-12-31T22:28:28Z","closed_at":"2013-12-31T23:59:11Z","open":"false","num_changes":"81","user":"47NOE","uid":"1811738","min_lat":"18.0813259","max_lat":"18.1163397","min_lon":"-63.0392394","max_lon":"-63.0205645","created_by":"Potlatch 2","build":"2.3-605-gbec0ea7","version":"2.3"}
{"id":"19739670","created_at":"2013-12-31T23:59:13Z","closed_at":"2013-12-31T23:59:15Z","open":"false","num_changes":"17","user":"mituc","uid":"1860759","min_lat":"37.0432953","max_lat":"37.0619236","min_lon":"-76.3896156","max_lon":"-76.3625439","created_by":"iD 1.3.4","imagery_used":"Bing"}
{"id":"19739671","created_at":"2013-12-31T23:59:16Z","closed_at":"2013-12-31T23:59:18Z","open":"false","num_changes":"29","user":"lollops","uid":"1811663","min_lat":"43.9561142","max_lat":"43.9629707","min_lon":"10.3236263","max_lon":"10.3294793","created_by":"iD 1.3.4","imagery_used":"Bing"}
```

i am collecting all  data and puting it into Database for analyses.
my question is how can i concentrate on one region. Germany for example.
as u see in json file this is data from all over the world. is it possible to say between lon = x and lat = y ?

With regards

Andrey 
ca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the changeset's bounding box (defined via `min_lat`,…,`max_lon`) is inside the region-polygon (if you use javascript, you can probably use [turf-intersect](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_intersect.html) for that). Then, there are three possible cases:

- The changeset's bbox is fully *inside* the region: we can be sure the changeset only affects data inside the region.
- The changeset's bbox is fully *outside* the region, the opposite is the case.
- When there is a partial overlap, the situation gets more complicated and it then depends on the actual changed content of the changeset (e.g. a changeset where a node in Canada and one in Australia is changed has an almost global bounding box and one can't say if the changeset affects a certain region by only looking at its metadata).

Unfortunately, there is no perfect solution out there for the last case. You can look at [OWL](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OWL) or probably also augmented diffs for possible approaches to that problem.